# How do i access every bookmark item in order to select\unselect them?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome Extension which opens all the user's bookmarks in tabs.

So far i've made the popup.html which opens in tabs the selected folder from the Bookmarks bar.

I'm making a settings page and i would like to know how can i access and display every single item of the user's Bookmarks in order to select a bookmark to exclude from opening with a checkbox.

In less words, i would like to:

```
Bookmarks bar
    ---> Bookmark1
    ---> Bookmark2            //display those bookmarks with a checkbox
    ---> Bookmark1
```

In order to have

```
Excluded bookmarks:
     [x]Bookmark 1
     [ ]Bookmark 2
     [x]Bookmark 3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the chrome.bookmarks API? Code would be good.

Comment: Yeah sure, i've already done the popup part. I need the settings part now, i just wrote how it is meant to be!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote code to list the contents of a chrome user's bookmarks to the console.log:

The **process_bookmark** function prints the bookmarks

The **chrome.browserAction.onClicked** is called when the user clicks the extension button

```
function process_bookmark(bookmarks) {

    for (var i =0; i < bookmarks.length; i++) {
        var bookmark = bookmarks[i];
        if (bookmark.url) {
            console.log("bookmark: "+ bookmark.title + " ~  " + bookmark.url);
        }

        if (bookmark.children) {
            process_bookmark(bookmark.children);
        }
    }
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  console.log("listing bookmarks: " );
  chrome.bookmarks.getTree( process_bookmark );
});
```

Google's bookmark docs are [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html)

Comment: This works well, if it doesn't work for you, make sure you have `"bookmarks"` permission in manifest file